# How to get rid of the @copydoc warning when producing code documentation using Doxygen?

Tags: key, warnings, standards, doxygen

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and doxygen 1.9.1.

When producing code documentation using Doxygen, I receive the following warning:

```
solver/linear/storage/aim/VrbBlkCompressedMCSRMatrix.h:66: warning: @copybrief or @copydoc target 'solver::linear::core::InnerLocalMatrix::foreachRowEntry( size_t, const std::function<void(size_t,size_t,double&)>& )' not found
```

Despite this message, the final documentation is correct. The problem is the warning; as it is a large code, we must avoid any warning.

The method is in solver/linear/core/InnerLocalMatrix.h;
Its structure is the following:

```
virtual void foreachRowEntry( size_t row, const std::function<void( size_t column, size_t index, double& value )>& function ) = 0;
```

This method is public.

The `EXTRACT_ALL`key in the Doxyfile is set to `YES`. I've tried several combinations of other Doxyfile keys, but the message is always the same.

The lines of the file VrbBlkCompressedMCSRMatrix.h related to this warning are:

```
 /// \copydoc solver::linear::core::InnerLocalMatrix::foreachRowEntry( size_t, const std::function<void(size_t,size_t,double&)>& )
  virtual void foreachRowEntry( size_t row, const std::function<void( size_t column, size_t index, double& value )>& function );
```

I suspect that the warning is related to the use of `std::function` as a parameter of the method, since in other parts of the same file, without using std::function, no problem occurs.

Does anyone know what is happening and how to get rid of the warnings? We cannot do without the warnings, and we cannot disable their display; we need to solve the problem.

A possible but not desirable solution is reproducing the comment block in `VrbBlkCompressedMCSRMatrix.h`. Still, I'd like to avoid this last resort because the same problem happens elsewhere.

I've tried to produced a code documentation using doxygen. I've received warnings when using `std::function` as a parameter of a function and tried to use `\copydoc` to copy the same documentation for another place.

Comment: The doxygen version 1.9.1 is a version from January 8, 2021, the current doxygen version is `.9.7 (released yesterday, May 18, 2023). I'd suggest to update to this version as, when my memory serves me well, this was a bug that has been fixed. When you are not able to update, would be a pity, please add, to the question, a small example so someone with the current version can have a go at it.

Comment: @albert, thank you for editing my message and your suggestion; unfortunately, using Doxygen 1.9.8 did not solve the problem.

Comment: Nice taking the master 1.9.8 version. please add, to the question, a small example showing the problem so we can have a go at it / see if there is a workaround.

Comment: @albert,what files should I create? A doxyfile, an .cpp and a .h?

Comment: The settings you use different from the default settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) a minimal `.cpp` and the `.h` belonging to that file so it is possible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @albert I was not able to reproduce the warnings in a small code. I'll try other alternatives and write back when I get it.